# Limit of a multivariate function

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to prove the following theorem.
Theorem: If $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} f(x,y)=L$ and  $\lim_{x\to a} f(x,y)$ and  $\lim_{y\to b} f(x,y)$ exist, then $$\lim_{x\to a} \lim_{y\to b}  f(x,y)= \lim_{y\to b} \lim_{x\to a}  f(x,y) =L.$$

This is how I tried this:

$$\forall ϵ>0,\exists δ_1>0;0<[(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2]<δ_1^2\implies|f(x,y)−L|<ϵ$$

$$\forall ϵ>0,\exists δ_2>0;0<|x−a|<δ_2\implies|f(x,y)−L1|<ϵ$$

$$\forall ϵ>0,\exists δ_3>0;0<|y−b|<δ_3\implies|f(x,y)−L2|<ϵ$$

And I know what I have to prove now is,

$$\forall ϵ>0,\exists δ>0;0<|x−a|<δ\implies|f(x,y)−g(y)|<ϵ$$
and
$$\forall ϵ>0,\exists δ>0;0<|y−b|<δ\implies|g(y)−L|<ϵ$$

defining $δ=\min(δ_1,δ_2,δ_3)$

I can t understand how to combine above 3 aruguments to get the conclusion I need.  Please help.

Comment: These two statements are not true:
$$\forall ϵ>0,\exists δ_2>0;0<|x−a|<δ_2\implies|f(x,y)−L|<ϵ$$
$$\forall ϵ>0,\exists δ_3>0;0<|y−b|<δ_3\implies|f(x,y)−L|<ϵ$$
In them, you are assuming that $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x,y) = L, \qquad \lim_{y\to b} f(x,y) = L$$
Which is something that you do not know, and in fact is generally false. All you know about those limits is that they converge, not what they converge to. Further the limit $\lim_{x\to a} f(x,y) = g(y)$ for some function $g$. That is, the limit value can still vary with $y$. Similarly, $\lim_{y\to b} f(x,y) = h(x)$ for some function $h$.

Comment: Okay I was mistaken. I edited my question. I want further help.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(y) = \lim_{x\to a} f(x, y)$. And let $\epsilon > 0$. Then for each $y$, there exists a $\delta_1(y)$ such that if $|y - b| < \delta_1(y)$, then $|f(x,y) - g(y)| < {\epsilon\over 2}$. Also there exists a $\delta_2$ such that if $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2} < \delta_2$ then $|f(x,y) - L| < {\epsilon\over 2}$.

Suppose $y$ satisfies $|y - b| < {\delta_2\over 2}$. Choose an $x$ such that $|x - a| < \delta_1(y)$ and $|x - a| < {\delta_2\over 2}$. Then $$\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2} \le |x - a| + |y -b| < {\delta_2\over 2} + {\delta_2\over 2} = \delta_2$$
So, $|f(x,y) - g(y)| < {\epsilon\over 2}$ and $|f(x,y) - L| < {\epsilon\over 2}$. Therefore
$$|g(y) - L| = |g(y) - f(x,y) + f(x,y) - L| \le |g(y) - f(x,y)| + |f(x,y) - L| < \epsilon$$
That is, for all $\epsilon > 0$ and all $y$ with $|y -b| < {\delta_2\over 2}$, we have $|g(y) - L| < \epsilon$. So,
$$\lim_{y\to b}\lim_{x\to a} f(x,y) = \lim_{y\to b} g(y) = L$$

Now define $h(y,x) = f(x, y)$. Then $\lim_{(y,x)\to(b,a)}h(y,x) = L$, and $\lim_{y\to b} h(y,x)$ exists for all $x$. So, by the result just proved, $$\lim_{x\to a}\lim_{y\to b} f(x,y) = \lim_{x\to a}\lim_{y\to b} h(y,x) =L$$.